# Which permissions needed to Offline access Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Currently, Offline_access of the Facebook api is deprecated. But I still want to post some articles on the wall of my users, even when they are not logged in to my website.

How do I do this right now? Which permissions do I need to post to the wall of a signed up users which is not logged in at my website?

I'm working in PHP. I hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the publish_stream extended permission as long as you have a valid access token.

Keep in mind that your initial access token will expire within 2 hours but you can make a call to extend the permission as long as you have a valid reason for doing so.

More information can be found here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/